# Convert ID3D11Texture2D into a memory buffer

Tags: directx-9, directx-11, directx-10

How can we convert `ID3D11Texture2D` into a memory buffer? I have `ID3D11Texture2D*` and need to read data from it to a memory buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a second texture with the same format/size, but create it as staging.

[Texture description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476253(v=vs.85).aspx)

Cpu access flags needs to be set to `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ`
and usage needs to be set to `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING`.

Then you can call `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource` to copy from the texture to the staging one.

And then you call [`Map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457(v=vs.85).aspx) to access data.